# How to use MySQLdb is_connected() to check an active mysql connection using python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to check if the mysql connection is active. How to do that in Python using MYSQLdb. I have tried the following from the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-ping.html):

```
conn.is_connected()
```

This returns AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'is_connected'.

Then i tried:

```
conn.ping(attempts=1, delay=0)
```

This returns: TypeError: ping() takes no keyword arguments

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you're pointing to is about `mysql-connector`, not `MySQLdb` (aka `mysql-python`; well, there are many Python DB API drivers for MySQL). The docs for MySQLdb are at http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

[Connection objects in MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#connection-objects) have `.ping()` method with one parameter and don't have `.is_connected()`.

You're looking for `conn.ping(True)`.

Comment: I need to have reconnect enabled in my mysql config right?

Comment: I don't do it. May be it's the default.

Comment: New in 1.2.2: Accepts an optional reconnect parameter. If True,
        then the client will attempt reconnection. Note that this setting
        is persistent. By default, this is on in MySQL<5.0.3, and off
        thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in MySQLdb， more elegant way is do not check whether the connection is active. Check whether the connection is active will also cause an exception if the mysql server close the connection sliently. Just leave it and use reconnect mechanism in a try except block.

In MySQLdb, there is a errorhandler in connection.py which will be used when error occured.

```
def defaulterrorhandler(connection, cursor, errorclass, errorvalue):
""" 

If cursor is not None, (errorclass, errorvalue) is appended to
cursor.messages; otherwise it is appended to
connection.messages. Then errorclass is raised with errorvalue as
the value.

You can override this with your own error handler by assigning it
to the instance.

"""
error = errorclass, errorvalue
if cursor:
    cursor.messages.append(error)
else:
    connection.messages.append(error)
del cursor
del connection
raise errorclass, errorvalue
```

see the '`del connection`'. It will close the connection and set the connection to None. so just let the error happen and after this we rebuild the world.

So you just need to implement an reconnect mechanism  in a try except block to deal with some problem such as Mysql has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try

```
if conn.open:
  do some code...
```

Comment: Whats the difference between them

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to use is_connection()

My understanding is that you're creating the connection through some code like

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=username, passwd=password, db=database)
```

if you print the results of dir(conn), it will show you all the properties and methods of that connection object. When I print that, is_connection is not there. There is a property `open` that returns `1` when your connection is open and `0` when it's closed. I use this in my code to check if the connection is open.

A small test in an interactive python console can help:

```
if conn.open:
    print('open')
else:
    print('closed')
```

Also if you read in the docs:

```
open = <member 'open' of '_mysql.connection' objects>
True if connection is open
```

http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/docs/MySQLdb.connections.html